# Create a text file with Textfield data and upload to firebase storage in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a Textfield in my Flutter app and I want to put the data of the field in a file and upload it into my Firebase storage on submit. I want to do this because the content is like a post on Twitter where you can write up to 400 characters in text and it would be better if it is in a seperated file.

Is that possible? I couldn't find any tutorial for this. Is there a better option than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, if I understand your question correct. It is possible to store each post as an own document. For example you can create a button and then you can upload your "post" to your firestore database. In your case it could look like this:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.send),
    onPressed: () {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").add(
        {
          "user": "user_xy",
          "text": "post_text"
        },
      );
    },
  )
```

You have to change the collection name to the name of your collection and the attributes to the attributes you require. The attribute `text` would store the message of your post. If you do it as shown above, each post get's stored as an own document.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer, but I was thinking more of an extra file, e.g. .txt where the data is written and uploaded to the firebase storage.

Comment: Ah okay. Have you seen this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3AtNC684vg ? This video shows a way how to upload an image the same way as shown above. I guess this could work with textfiles as well.

Comment: Yes, it could work but I don't know how to put data of an textfield into a text file. But I think it could be better and easier if I do it with the Firestore database. Thanks for your help.